# How to change mysql user password by the user himself not by admin/root?

Tags: mysql, database

How to change **mysql** user password by the user himself not by admin/root?
I mean, for a user `john` -

1. the dba creates the user `john` and sets the default password to `john1234`
2. now `john` is able to connect to mysql server.
3. `john` now wants to change his password to `john4321`, so that even the dba admin is not aware of the changed password.
4. infact, in my usecase, the root password is lost (hhmmm, and i think there is no way to recover it from the encrypted password string). But I am still fine if `john` can change his password himself.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

Normally your should be able to change your own password. The command is

```
SET PASSWORD = PASSWORD('john4321');
```

The only way to know whether you have the right is to try.
If you have a few ideas what the old password was you could compare the result of

```
SELECT PASSWORD ('possible old password');
```

to the hash in the table mySQL.user, if you have access to it.
21/02/2022 I have just created a user with no rights whatsoever. When I logged in as the new user I successfully ran the command:

```
SET PASSWORD = PASSWORD('1234');
```

and when I relogged in with password 1234 it worked.

Comment: `SQL > SET PASSWORD = password('john4321');` output: 
`ERROR: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'password('john4321')' at line 1`  ++1